# Orbeon Vertical scroll bar in Safari and IE close autocomplete menu

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, autocomplete, safari, orbeon

I'm using Orbeon v2017.1 and I've added an autocomplete field.

The dropdown is correctly displayed and can be scrolled with the mouse wheel, up/down arrows and by clicking on the scroll bar in all browsers **except** *Safari* and *IE*.

In these two browsers the dropdown menu closes when clicking on the scroll bar, but it works correctly in the two other cases.
Is there a possible way to solve this?

Please don't mind the styling, I've posted a .gif of the behaviour.

[image]

I see that this is a known issue  (please refer to: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/705) but I'm not sure how this could be solved within Orbeon.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Orbeon doesn't use typeahead.js, but it looks like a different problem. The autocomplete is due for a refresh and the best thing to do is probably rewrite it entirely. There is an RFE for that. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1433

Comment: Hi ebruchez, thanks for the info. I will try to find another solution for now.

I'm currently facing another issue with autocomplete (I'd like to load the data for the dropdown from my service when the form loads, could you please also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042578/orbeon-static-autocomplete if it's not a problem? Thanks in advance)