# Orbeon autocomplete - Not working properly when initially hidden and readonly

Tags: autocomplete, orbeon

I'm using Orbeon version 2017.1 and I have autocomplete control `mode = resource` which is initially hidden and readonly.
When it becomes visible and not-readonly if I start typing something in the control nothing is suggested.
What I can see in the source is that the result is successfully retrieved into select element `fr-autocomplete-select1`, but the values are not populated into the list element `fr-autocomplete-yui-div` and therefore not displayed. 
After some debugging, I see that autoComplete.dynamicItemset in autocomplete.js always returns false in this case because the element `fr-autocomplete-dynamic-itemset` initially doesn't have any value, and afterwards is not reset.

Comment: Is this for a form you created with Form Builder? Could you try to see if the problem persists with 2018.1? If so, would you be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that we can run here, and attach it a response so we can look into it?

Comment: It's created using Form Builder, but now I also figured out that there is some custom logic for all autocomplete fields in our project. However, autocomplete controls work fine in all other cases except this one, when it's hidden and read-only initially. After removing this custom logic, it works fine for us, but I still see that the logic in autocomplete.js has a bit different flow in this case - dynamicItemset has value false. Unfortunately, I'm using Orbeon forms within a different application, so I'm not able to try it out with 2018.1 at the moment.

Comment: Are you saying that the autocomplete works fine if you remove your own "custom logic"? Is so, what is that custom logic? Is that XForms you have a custom model, or did you edit the source of the form? -Alex

Comment: Yes, autocomplete works fine if we remove custom logic. Our custom logic is javascript logic which we added in order to resolve issue described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006117/orbeon-vertical-scroll-bar-in-safari-and-ie-close-autocomplete-menu. We resolved that by adding leading space on focus on this input fields within autocomplete control.

Comment: And because of that it's not possible to go through this condition in orbeon's autocomplete.js `if (this.isDynamicItemset() || option.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) == 0 || query == "")` because query contains leading space, but the answers from our service trim this leading space and return results without it. And as I already mentioned, unfortunately only in this case `this.isDynamicItemset()` returns false

Comment: Got it; I'm afraid that issues caused by an integration you've done with `typeahead.js` which Orbeon Forms doesn't support out-of-the-box goes beyond what we can help with in the community. If your organization is using Orbeon Forms PE, I'd recommend you raise this problem through your PE support channel.